# Issue in the react native tensorflow with expo

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

I trained the image using the teachable machine Google and exported the model to the tensor flow
I imported but it's giving me the wrong prediction.

I have trained 12500 for dog and cat images and it was predicting properly in the system , but here it giving a false one.

here is the model
[Model](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1l1qMaTwjGhOvkZXooQlzw4qZ5Jy7oZ5F?usp=sharing)

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "animal_detection",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.3",
    "@react-native/assets-registry": "^0.73.0",
    "@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd": "^2.2.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.5.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu": "~3.11.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "~3.11.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "~3.11.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.8.0",
    "@types/react-native-canvas": "^0.1.9",
    "expo": "47.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "8.7.0",
    "expo-camera": "13.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker":"~14.0.2",
    "expo-gl": "12.0.1",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "^11.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "react-native-canvas": "^0.1.39",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.14.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { bundleResourceIO } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { cameraWithTensors } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';

const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

const App = () => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [model, setModel] = useState(null);
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);

  async function loadModel() {
    const modelJson = require('./model/model.json');
    const modelWeights = require('./model/weights.bin');

    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights));

    setModel(model);
  }

  const handleCameraStream = async (images, updatePreview, gl) => {
    const loop = async () => {
      const imageTensor = images.next().value;
      if (imageTensor) {
        const resizedImage = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imageTensor, [224, 224]);
        const normalizedImage = resizedImage.cast('float32').div(127.5).sub(1);
        const inputTensor = normalizedImage.expandDims(0); // Add extra dimension
        const prediction = await model.predict(inputTensor);
        console.log(prediction);
        console.log(prediction.dataSync());
        const catProbability = prediction.dataSync()[0]; // Access the probability values
        const dogProbability = prediction.dataSync()[1];

        console.log("Cat Probability:", catProbability);
        console.log("Dog Probability:", dogProbability);
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    loop();
  };

  const handleCaptureImage = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
      predictImage(photo.uri);
    }
  };

  const handlePickImage = async () => {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      Alert.alert('Permission Required', 'Please grant camera roll permissions to pick an image.');
      return;
    }

    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: false,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      predictImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  const predictImage = async (imageUri) => {
    const imageTensor = await loadImageTensor(imageUri);
    if (imageTensor) {
      //const inputTensor = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imageTensor, [224, 224]).cast('float32').div(127.5).sub(1).expandDims(0);
      //const prediction = await model.predict(inputTensor);
      //const inputTensor = imageTensor.cast('float32').div(127.5).sub(1).expandDims(0);
      const resizedImage = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imageTensor, [224, 224]);
      const normalized = resizedImage.cast('float32').div(127.5).sub(1).expandDims(0);
      const prediction = await model.predict(normalized);

      console.log(prediction);
      console.log(prediction.dataSync());
      const catProbability = prediction.dataSync()[0]; // Access the probability values
      const dogProbability = prediction.dataSync()[1];

      console.log("Cat Probability:", catProbability);
      console.log("Dog Probability:", dogProbability);
    }
  };

  const loadImageTensor = async (imageUri) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(imageUri);
      const imageData = await response.arrayBuffer();
      const imageBuffer = new Uint8Array(imageData);
      const imageTensor = tf.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);
      return imageTensor;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error loading image:', error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
      await tf.ready();
      await loadModel();
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;

  }

  if (model === null) {
    return <Text>Loading model...</Text>;
  }


  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

      <TensorCamera
        ref={cameraRef}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
        cameraTextureHeight={1080}
        cameraTextureWidth={1920}
        resizeHeight={224}
        resizeWidth={224}
        onReady={handleCameraStream}
        autorender={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```